# detached entity passed to persist in SpringBoot app

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file I have this entity:
I have a user entity with a company

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_user")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {



 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Company company;

}
```

I create a company, I save it, and next, I attached it to the User:

```
user.setCompany(companyService.findAll().iterator().next());
```

but When I save the user, I got this error:

```
detached entity passed to persist: com.elcor.backend.persistence.domain.backend.Company
```

and Here the createUser method in the service layer

```
  @Transactional
    public User createUser(User user, Set<UserRole> userRoles) {

        User localUser = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());

        if (localUser != null) {
            LOG.info("User with username {} and email {} already exist. Nothing will be done. ",
                    user.getUsername(), user.getEmail());
        } else {

            String encryptedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
            user.setPassword(encryptedPassword);

            //Plan plan = new Plan(plansEnum);
            // It makes sure the plans exist in the database
            //if (!planRepository.exists(plansEnum.getId())) {
             //   plan = planRepository.save(plan);
            //}

            //user.setPlan(plan);

            for (UserRole ur : userRoles) {
                roleRepository.save(ur.getRole());
            }

            user.getUserRoles().addAll(userRoles);


            localUser = userRepository.save(user);

        }

        return localUser;
    }
```

Comment: does this call `companyService.findAll().iterator().next()` return you a company with id ?

Comment: yes, it returns a company with id

Comment: Can you add the statement where you save the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` which has the persist 
and it tries to persist an entity that was already detached from persistence context.

So try remove the CascadeType.PERSIST bu using:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE,
                      CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH },
                      fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Company company;
```

Comment: could you please post the Company class with user mapping line

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is with cascading.
If you want to use CascadeType.ALL then don't save the company and user separately.
Whatever the company entity that you are trying to save attach it to user entity and then save only the user entity.
The company entity will be automatically persisted.